# Extracting and re-using subplots in Julia

Tags: julia, plots.jl, julia-plots, controlsystems.jl

How can I extract and reuse/combine subplots in Julia? Consider:

```
pp =  plot(0:0.01:2, [sin.(0:0.01:2), cos.(0:0.01:2)], layout=(1,2));
gg =  plot(0:0.01:2, [sin.(0:0.01:2).^2, cos.(0:0.01:2).^2], layout=(1,2));
```

Both `pp` and `gg` report length 2 and are indexable, for example like: `pp[1]` and `gg[2]` etc.

```
julia> typeof(pp)
Plots.Plot{Plots.GRBackend}

julia> length(pp)
2

julia> pp[2]
Subplot{2}
```

How can I know extract and reuse these subplots? I tried:

```
mixed = plot(pp[1], gg[2], layout=(1,2))
```

expecting that Julia would know how to put Subplot objects into a new "plot container"; but no dice.

Of course I know I can make/do:

```
p1 = plot(0:0.01:2, sin.(0:0.01:2)
p2 = plot(0:0.01:2, cos.(0:0.01:2)
pp = plot(p1, p2, ...)
```

so I have re-usable pieces; but that is not my question.

**Use case:** Consider the output of [`bodeplot`](https://juliacontrol.github.io/ControlSystems.jl/stable/lib/plotting/#ControlSystemsBase.bodeplot). If I have multiple transfer functions whose Bode plots I have already made and I want to reuse the magnitude plot from one system (`Subplot{1}` in the result) and the phase plot from *another* system (`Subplot{2}` in the result) this would have been an easy way to do it.

**Note:** For the example use case mentioned `ControlSystems.jl` does have a `plotphase=true` which can be supplied to the `bodeplot` call to just get the magnitude plot. These can then be combined as appropriate. **However**, I see no way to get just the phase plots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there is indeed a method to do this documented in the source code.  On checking

```
methods(plot)
```

one sees that the following signatures are defined:

```
plot(sp::Plots.Subplot, args...; kw...)
plot(plt1::Plots.Plot, plt2::Union{Plots.PlaceHolder, Plots.Plot}, 
     plts_tail::Union{Plots.PlaceHolder, Plots.Plot}...; kw...)
plot(plt::Plots.Plot, args...; kw...)
plot(args...; kw...)
```

The very first of these can be used to "promote" the `Plots.Subplot` to `Plots.Plot` at which point one can use the second form of the function. So

```
mixed = plot(map(plot, [pp[1], gg[2]])..., layout=(1,2))
```

works instead.